# Implied volatility curve

Tags: implied-volatility

I was trying to build the implied volatility curve from SP500 options.
In order to adjust the liquidity issue, I used put-call parity to generate the call price from the OTM Put price.(plot 1)

But when I plot the implied volatility curve, there is a "cliff" in the middle.(plot 2)

I think the volatility should be the same as Call or Put, so the curve should be smooth.
Can someone explain this to me and how to fix the problem?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: can you add some details regarding your data (source, did you use bid/ask/mid?) and some details regarding the methodology?

Comment: If these are long-term options, remember to adjust for risk-free interest

Comment: This is the SPX option date from yfinance.

Comment: please share exact methodology and relevant code snippets

Comment: Actually, it is not reached the BS model yet. The implied volatility data point is extracted from yahoo finance. You can see the left-wing as the vol from Put option and the right-wing as the vol from Call. I just don't know why the general Put's vol is lower than Call's vol.

Comment: To get puts and calls to line up you need to adjust the rate you are using when implying vols.